# Angular/AG-Grid - customized columns menu tab

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm working with Angular + AG-Grid and my goal is to add an icon next to a columnMenuTab > column list items. I don't want to create a new component and place it in menuTabs, the reason is I have multiple AG-Grid tables AND the TONS of columns with TONS of properties, plus if there is a way to simply override the existing tab it would save the time of writing the checkbox functionalities over again for a simple icon.

> Imagine Col 1, Test col, Col 2, etc. Having an icon in the right side that is appeared on hover

[image]